# Bootstrap toggle is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

am actually developing an django application for warehouses an stockists. I am trying to get a list of stockist per warehouse in a list button. This button show a modal that make a query by an ajax consult with the name, position and permissions of all the stockists assigned to a specific warehouse. I want to show a toggle button from bootstrap in my modal, and i refresh the bootstrapToggle function and it show the next message  `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootstrapToggle is not a function`

Actually all the javascript code is this:

```
var token = '{{csrf_token}}';
$('#Modal_list').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
    var urlToAjax = button.data('urlstockists');
    console.log(urlToAjax);
    var recipient = button.data('pk'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
    console.log(recipient);                
        $.ajax({
            headers: { "X-CSRFToken": token },
            url: urlToAjax,
            type: 'POST',
            data: {'id':recipient},
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data)
                var htmldata=""
                if(data.length==0){
                    htmldata += '<div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800"> There are no assigned stockists </div>'
                }else{
                    for(var i = 0; i<data.length; i++){
                        htmldata += '<div class="card border-left-primary shadow h-100 py-2">\
                                        <div class="card-body">\
                                            <div class="row no-gutters align-items-center">\
                                                <div class="col mr-2">\
                                                    <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">Name: '+data[i].fields.name+'</div>\
                                                    <div class="h5 mb-0 font-weight-bold text-gray-800">Position: '+data[i].fields.position+ '</div>\
                                                    <div class="form-group">\
                                                        <label> Grant input\
                                                            <input type="checkbox" class="newToggle" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="On" data-off="Off" data-onstyle="warning">\
                                                        </label>\
                                                        <label> Grant output\
                                                            <input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" data-on="On" data-off="Off" data-onstyle="warning">\
                                                        </label>\
                                                    </div>\
                                                </div>\
                                                <div class="col-auto">\
                                                    <i class="fas fa-user fa-2x text-gray-300"></i>\
                                                </div>\
                                            </div>\
                                        </div>\
                                    </div> <br>';
                    }     
                }
                $('#stck').html(htmldata);
                $('.newToggle').bootstrapToggle();
            }
        });
    var modal = $(this);
    modal.find('.modal-body #stock').val(recipient)
});
```

Comment: How is this a Django question exactly ??? (tag removed)

Comment: U have the reason, sorry

Answer (score 2):

That element you're grabbing is dynamic, so you need to reference something that already existed on the page, try this:

```
$('body .newToggle').bootstrapToggle();
```

Comment: i got the same error, i think that i need to get a bind function from bootstrap, could it be the solution?

Comment: silly question, but you've included the bootstrapToggle library correct?

Comment: Yes, i have other toggle buttons in another templates and they work correctly. And i had import the toggle library before the ajax script

Comment: Hmmm, ok after looking at it closer it's absolutely that it doesn't know about the bootstrapToggle function.  Are the 'other templates' on the same page?  Something about your import of the script must not be working, can you 100% confirm the library is actually present at the time of the $('#Modal_list').on('show.bs.modal', function being fired?

Comment: How could i confirm if the library is present in the jqery modal?

Comment: looks like you can safely call .bootstrapToggle(); on an element that doesn't exist.  so right after $('#Modal_list').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) { 
    $('#Modal_list .notrealthing').bootstrapToggle()   - if you get the same error then you don't have the library included

Comment: I got the same error, but how can i include the library into a modal? i tried in a delete modal, and i got the same error. And really thats the problem, it doesn't found the library into a jquery modal.

Comment: you should just have to include the script and style tags found here: https://www.bootstraptoggle.com/ in the HTML before you execute this call

Comment: I already have them, it is not the error. I tried with a button function on click and it doesn't work

Comment: at this point, for me to help you I need to see all the relevant parts of the code.  For some reason, when it executes the line with 'bootstrapToggle()' - it has no idea what bootstrapToggle is, which almost certainly means it's not referenced yet.  Can you post the code where you include the proper libraries? maybe in a code snippet.