# Error when creating dynamic bootstrap toggle button

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have some Bootstrap toggle buttons which I don't want them to be static anymore. I'd like to load them at runtime. This is the html code I use

```
<a>
Test-Title

<input checked data-onstyle="success"
       data-toggle="toggle" id="myToggleID" onchange="toggleElement(this.id)"
       type="checkbox">
</a>
```

How could I implement the above in javascript?
I've tried

```
var input = $('input[type="checkbox"]').bootstrapToggle();
```

but I get the following error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).bootstrapToggle is not a function

I've looked several questions but didn't manage to solve the issue yet.

Comment: Try `console.log($('input[type="checkbox"]'))`. What do you see? If you see `null`, then the element is not being found.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap toggle is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59969008/bootstrap-toggle-is-not-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that has the same problem, the reason for that error was because I imported the bootstrap javascript before importing the jQuery one.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation. [https://www.bootstraptoggle.com/][1]

Scroll down to where it says 'Initialize by JavaScript'

It uses a JavaScript IIFE function to set the data-toggle attribute of the checkbox with id="toggle-one". Make sure you load the bootstrapToggle script before your IIFE.